# MVC - show only chosen "bookings" - can't think of a way how to

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I've got a Restaurant with possible creating restaurants and bookings, then choose see the bookings for a specific time frame, but I can't think of a way to how to fix the issue of "just showing the chosen restaurant bookings."

My Index.cshtml is showing the following right now:

```
<div class="well">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Booking", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <label for="StartDate">Display bookings for</label>

            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Restaurants.Count, Model.Restaurants.Select(r => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = r.Name,
                Value = r.Id.ToString(),
                Selected = r.Id == Model.Restaurants.Count

            }));

        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Restaurants)

        <br/>
        @Html.TextBox("StartDate", Model.StartDate.Value.ToShortDateString())
        <text>-</text>
        @Html.TextBox("EndDate", Model.EndDate.Value.ToShortDateString())
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" class="btn btn-default"/>
    }
</div>
```

The StartDate and EndDate come from a controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(BookingsListView view)
        {
            if (view.StartDate == null)
                view.StartDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
            if (view.EndDate == null)
                view.EndDate = DateTime.Now.Date;

            var endDateLimit = view.EndDate.Value.AddDays(1);

            view.Bookings = from b in db.Bookings.Include("Restaurant")
                where b.StartTime >= view.StartDate && b.StartTime < endDateLimit
                select b;

            view.Restaurants = dbRestaurant.Restaurants.OrderBy(r => r.Id).ToList();

            return View(view);
        }
```

My brain is not going anywhere right now, can't think of a way how to just display the the bookings of the "chosen" restaurant.

Any suggestions, ideas from where to start?

Comment: Would you like to display this in the index view?

Comment: @MuyiwaOlu-Ogunleye Yes, at the moment it's a small "test" programme, so these bookings go to the index page, at least the filter by date is setup here.

Answer (score 0):

In your `BookingListView`, include a property called selected like:

```
public int Selected {get; set;}
```

And then, in your view, replace the `DropDownListFor` to the following:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Selected, Model.Restaurants.Select(r => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = r.Name,
            Value = r.Id.ToString(),
            Selected = r.Id == Model.Restaurants.Count

        }));
```

In your controller, the `Selected` property should represent the Id of the selected Resturaunt like so (note the comment after `endDateLimit` and in the view.restaurants declaration.):

```
public ActionResult Index(BookingsListView view)
    {
        if (view.StartDate == null)
            view.StartDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
        if (view.EndDate == null)
            view.EndDate = DateTime.Now.Date;

        var endDateLimit = view.EndDate.Value.AddDays(1);

        // Use view.Selected to find the current selected resturant
        if(view.Selected == 0) // nothing has been selected
             view.Selected = 1 //ID of default resturant?

        view.Bookings = from b in db.Bookings.Include("Restaurant")
            where b.StartTime >= view.StartDate && b.StartTime < endDateLimit
            select b;

        // Only selected restuarants

        view.Restaurants = dbRestaurant.Restaurants.Where(r => r.Id == view.Selected).OrderBy(r => r.Id).ToList();

        return View(view);
    }
```

The reason your earlier code wasn't working is because `DropdownListFor` adds the value of the selected item to the first parameter, therefore you were actually assigning the selected ID to the count of the collection (which wouldn't work as the count is a method).

The fix assigns it to a property of the View Model which allows it to be retrievable at will.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the thing. Now if I look at the page - I see only the..

1. The restaurant ID I've chosen.
2. Still doesn't filter the bookings by restaurant, showing all of the bookings. Am I missing something?

[I see only "the restaurant by ID" but I want to see all restaurants and filter the view to see only the bookings for the restaurant I chose.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/881Ok.jpg)

---

I've got this one fixed now.

I've added a LINQ to the query in my Index:

```
//Choose restaurant by ID and show the bookings for it.
            view.Bookings = from b in db.Bookings.Include("Restaurant")
                where (view.RestaurantId == null || view.RestaurantId == b.Restaurant.Id) &&
                       b.StartTime >= view.StartDate && b.StartTime < endDateLimit 
                select b;
```

and in the BookingListView, there's the following:

```
public int? RestaurantId { get; set; }
```

The DropDownList for it has been changed to:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RestaurantId, Model.Restaurants.Select(r => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = r.Name,
                Value = r.Id.ToString(),
                Selected = r.Id == Model.Restaurants.Count

            }));
```

[All done.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hv02Q.jpg)